# How to use array values as a case in a switch statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

I have an array of values:

```
const array = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'];
```

I want to use each of the values as a case in a switch statement:

```
switch (???) {
 case 'first':
  console.log('This is first');
  break;
 case 'second':
  console.log('This is second');
  break;
 case 'third':
  console.log('This is third');
  break;
 case 'fourth':
  console.log('This is fourth');
  break;
 default:
 console.log('None');
}
```

Values in an array are generated automatically, so it is not a fixed-size array. I can't come up with an expression in between parentheses. Should this be done somehow with a forEach? Should I first split values? But what then? Store them in a separate variable?

Comment: please add `???`. what is the input?

Comment: I'm trying to come up with input. Input should be either 'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'

Comment: So put it in a function and call your function with a forEach or a for loop. You are overthinking it.

Comment: You can have something like `switch(array[index])`, where `index` is a variable

Comment: `switch` and `forEach` would do two opposite things: `switch` will execute only one code block, depending on the array item passed, `forEach` would execute the code for each and every item in the array so they are not interchangeable. Which of the two results do you want to obtain?

Comment: what are you doing with the array?

Answer (score 1):

Put the switch in a function. Call the function with a forEach or a for loop with the index.

```js
function runCommand(command) {
  switch (command) {
    case 'first':
      console.log('This is first');
      break;
    case 'second':
      console.log('This is second');
      break;
    case 'third':
      console.log('This is third');
      break;
    case 'fourth':
      console.log('This is fourth');
      break;
    default:
      console.log('None');
  }
}

const array = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'];
array.forEach(runCommand);

for (let i=0; i<array.length;i++ ){
  runCommand(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    switch (array[i]) {
        case 'first':
            console.log('This is first');
            break;
        case 'second':
            console.log('This is second');
            break;
        case 'third':
            console.log('This is third');
            break;
        case 'fourth':
            console.log('This is fourth');
            break;
        default:
            console.log('None');
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be reduced further with a `for...of` loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use only one value at a time in switch statement because switch statement is meant for comparing one value with multiple option that's why we use it.

if you want to use switch statement with all of values that are in array then you need to loop an array .

```
  array.forEach(currValue => {
      switch(currValue){
          case 'first':
      console.log('This is first');
      break;
      ...
      }
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const array = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'];
```

Make a function, run your foreach inside the function and your switch inside your loop

```
function looparray(arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(value, index) {
    switch (value) {
      case 'first':
        console.log('This is first');
        break;
      case 'second':
        console.log('This is second');
        break;
      case 'third':
        console.log('This is third');
        break;
      case 'fourth':
        console.log('This is fourth');
        break;
      default:
        console.log('None');
    }
  });

}
```

Then of course run your function with your array as parameter

```
looparray(array);
```

Answer (score -2):

so what is it?

```
switch (array[0]) {
```

What a story, Mark?

Comment: I don't know how much items will be in an array

Comment: So make a loop....

Comment: then switch probably won't suit for you

Answer (score -3):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
switch (???) {
 case myArray[0]:
  console.log('This is first');
  break;
 case myArray[1]:
  console.log('This is second');
  break;
 case myArray[2]:
  console.log('This is third');
  break;
 case myArray[3]:
  console.log('This is fourth');
  break;
 default:
 console.log('None');
}
```

Comment: This may not be suitable for an unlimited amount of entries in `myArray`.